# IIOException when reading image

Tags: java, image

SOLVED!  crew4ok helped and others too,Thanks!Error in the following section of code. I am trying to load a png image into a BufferedImage type but can't do so, and I'm working in ubuntu.I have a root directory called TicTacToe and under it i have src and res folder.In src i have my java files and in res i have a png image.When i am trying to access png file from res folder it gives error.
link for my directory structure:http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=210aamd&s=5#.Up38mLUW3h8

```
package com.blogspot.edwn112;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel; 
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class Game extends JFrame implements MouseListener {
private JPanel panel = new JPanel();
private JPanel gameArea = new JPanel();
private JButton button = new JButton("Play Again");
private JLabel label;
private BufferedImage resizedImage;

public Game() {
    addMouseListener(this);
    panel.add(button);
    BufferedImage image = null;

    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(new File("/TicTacToe/res/tictactoe.png"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    resizedImage = resize(image, 100, 100);

    gameArea.add(label);
    add(gameArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}

public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
}

public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
}

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
}

public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
}

public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
}

public static BufferedImage resize(BufferedImage image, int width,
        int height) {
    BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(width, height,
            BufferedImage.TRANSLUCENT);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) bi.createGraphics();
    g2d.addRenderingHints(new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY));
    g2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height, null);
    g2d.dispose();
    return bi;
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(resizedImage, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error in native look");
    }
    JFrame frame = new Game();
    frame.setTitle("Tic Tac Toe");
    frame.setSize(400, 300);
    // frame.pack();
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Error:
     Archive for required library:'res/tictactoe.png' in project'TicTacToe' cannot be read                                                 or is not a valid ZIP file
     javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
        at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1301)

Comment: The file probably doesn't exist.

Comment: i saw other posts but it seem no help to me so i asked, what can i do other than that.

Comment: Note that `"TicTacToe/res/tictactoe.png"` is a relative path. What is the current working directory that this is referenced from? Does the directory and file exist?

Comment: current directory is /TicTacToe/src/com/blogspot/edwn112 and file exists in /TicTacToe/res/tictactoe.png

Comment: Try to work using the full path.

Answer (score 0):

If the project root folder is TicTacToe, you want to just use **`"res/tictactoe.png"`** as the file path.

```
TicTacToe (project root dir)
        res
           tictacttoe.png
        src
```

When you use this `"TicTacToe/res/tictactoe.png"` You saying that the file structure is like this

```
ProjectRoot
          TicTacToe
                  res
                     tictactoe.png
```

Comment: done that too, but no use

Comment: Is TicTacToe your project name? How are you running the program, through and IDE like eclipse or netbeans, or are you running from the command line?

Comment: Are you running from the command line? If you are you may the image in a different location

Comment: look the link for the photo of the project i m using eclipse

Comment: Are you sure this `res/tictactoe.png` didn't work. Works fine for me every time give the file file structure like yours

Comment: it works for me too but not this project .. i don't know why?

Comment: If nothing else works, all I can suggest it try taking the image and putting it directly in the project root and calling it like `"tictactoe.png"`. And if that doesn't work, try putting it in the bin in the same directory as the class file and calling it from `"tictactoe.png"`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried new File(getClass().getResource("// path to tictactoe"); ?

Answer (score 0):

Does you app have enough permissions to read the file?
I found theese lines in ImageIO.read() sources:

```
if (!input.canRead()) {
    throw new IIOException("Can't read input file!");
}
```

And input.canRead() in turn gives us:

```
public boolean canRead() {
    SecurityManager security = System.getSecurityManager();
    if (security != null) {
        security.checkRead(path);
    }
    return fs.checkAccess(this, FileSystem.ACCESS_READ);
}
```

Comment: i have given full access rights, read, write and execute..still same problem

Comment: Try to check the file with File.exists first.

Comment: Actually your path is written like this: "/TicTacToe/res/tictactoe.png" - with the leading slash present. In linux leading slash specify that the directory after the slash is located in a root of a file system.
So i guess you should use something like "../../../res/tictactoe.png".

Comment: javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
 at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1301)
 at com.blogspot.edwn112.Game.<init>(Game.java:35)
 at com.blogspot.edwn112.Game.main(Game.java:84)

Comment: Are you sure then that your current folder is TicTacToe/src/com/blogspot/edwn112? How do you run the app?

Comment: i just hit the debug sign

Comment: Error: Archive for required library:'res/tictactoe.png' in project'TicTacToe' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file

Comment: I've just tried running test project in Eclipse: the start dir for the app is the project dir. So you should use "res/tictactoe.png".
At least it worked for me :)

Comment: it worked..changed compiler to jdk_1.7.0_45 and created new project and used "res/tictactoe.png" instead "/res/tictactoe.png".Thanks a lot!

Comment: well...glad that worked someway :)